# Auto Scroll During jQuery Drag

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I'm considering adding drag and drop functionality to my Webforms application.

One consideration is that the drag source and drop target may be far enough away from each other to require scrolling. So I thought a cool UI would be for an overlay to appear at the top and bottom of the browser window when the user starts to drag.

This overlay would be a shaded area with an arrow (the top overlay would have an Up arrow and the bottom overlay would have a Down arrow). When the user drags over the overlay, the window would scroll in that direction.

Questions:

1. Does anyone have any experience with anything like this? Do you know if it can be done reliably across browsers?
2. Can anyone recommend a jQuery plugin that could do the heavy lifting?
3. Any other thoughts or recommendations?

Comment: this seems to be kind of what you want, you should take a look at this part of the jqueryui part
http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#scroll

Comment: Man, that seems buggy as hell, at least in Chrome. Once it starts scrolling, I can no longer see the item I'm dragging. Also, that seems a terrible choice to stop scrolling when I stop moving the mouse.

Comment: In my (jQuery Ui) application the scrolling happens automatically when dragging beyond the div's border... Not bragging here, I didn't do anything (no overlays or anything). Just whish resizing a child elelment would affect the same..

Comment: @T4NK3R: Can you be more specific? Are you using the draggable component? And did you see my comment above about the bugs I saw after playing with it a few minutes? Are you saying you don't see any of those?

Comment: Yes, completely standard .draggable() (jQuery 1.7.1 and Ui 1.8.23). I don't use any arrow-overlays to kickstart scrolling, the page (not a div) starts scrolling "by itself" when I drag up against the window borders : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got also some issues with that functionality. I solved it by styling my draggable element with `margin: 0` and `padding: 0` and make it consistent with a `width` and a `height` properties.

More I used `margin` and `padding` properties on draggable, sortable and droppable elements more I had issues.

Hope it will help you !